# How to properly clone a jsPlumb draggable

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am using the latest community edition of jsPlumb.  I am trying to enable drag-n-drop of items from a toolbox into a jsPlumb diagram.

```
jsPlumb.draggable('decision', {
  clone: true,
  grid:[10,10]
});
```

I can start draggin but when I drop the element into the jsPlumb Container I get the following error

`jsPlumb function failed : TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
jsPlumb.draggable(clone, { containment:'decision'});
```